# How to programmatically set To File block parameters in a Simulink model?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am trying to programmaticaly add [To File](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/tofile.html) block to existing Simulink model.

```
open_system('myModel, 'loadonly');
add_block('simulink/Sinks/To File', 'myModel/MyFileBlock');
```

This was successful, but further steps are unclear:

How do I define input to the To File block?
How do I set parameters: 'File name', 'Variable name', etc.?

For parameters, I tried to specify optional comma-separated pairs of Name,Value arguments, like so:

```
add_block('simulink/Sinks/To File', 'myModel/MyFileBlock', 'File name', 'myOutput.m')
```

but I got error: *ToFile block does not have a parameter named 'File name'*.

I also tried

```
set_param(''myModel/MyFileBlock', 'File name', 'myOutput.m')
```

but got the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that should work, there may be a better way to do this:

```
open_system('myModel', 'loadonly');
add_block('simulink/Sinks/To File', 'myModel/MyFileBlock');
set_param('myModel/MyFileBlock','FileName','myOutput.mat');
set_param('myModel/MyFileBlock','MatrixName','myMatrix');
set_param('myModel/MyFileBlock','SaveFormat','Timeseries');
% etc...
```

You can find a list of the relevant [block-specific properties](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/block-specific-parameters.html#mw_37d2fd98-b38c-48fe-8568-e2269b0cb6d8) in the documentation:

[image]

Comment: Yes, it was about parameter name, which is `FileName`, thanks.